# Yii2 relation выборка изображений для сущностей

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, phpmyadmin, activerecord

Существует модель **Image** в которой хранятся, как понятно из названия, изображения. Каждое отдельное изображение прикрепляется к любой другой модели посредством указания полей **modelName** и **itemId**.

Не могу сообразить как сделать жадную выборку. Для связанных таблиц через FK можно делать выборки через **hasOne** и **hasMany**, а вот как сделать без этой связи понять не могу. Как то жалко для каждой отдельной модели делать по одному лишнему запросу.

Сам модуль изображений для yii2 скачал и установил отдельно, можно глянуть на вот этом репозитории [yii2-images](https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images).

Comment: Пробовали вот это решение? https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/issues/29#issuecomment-157000440

Comment: Что-то подобное пробовал, не работало, сейчас попробовал это решение, тоже не работает

Comment: хотя вот почему-то в самой модели нет связанных с ней изображений, а вот запросов в базу стало меньше, хм

Comment: Все потому, что-то where возвращает объект Query, а не ActiveQuery. Но видимо из-за того, что выборка все равно проходит правильно yii где-то кэширует данные что ли, в любом случае работает спасибо. Если получится преобразовать это решение более по человечески - отпишусь.

Comment: можно вместо where использовать `onCondition`

Comment: о да, это то что нужно, спасибо, а какая принципиальная разница между этими методами и почему они возвращают разные типы объектов?

Comment: вот конечное решение  

`return $this->hasOne(Image::className(), ['itemId' => 'id'])
            ->onCondition(['modelName' => $this->tableName()]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Вместо метода `where()` следует использовать `onCondition()`

```
return $this->hasOne(Image::className(), ['itemId' => 'id'])
            ->onCondition(['modelName' => $this->tableName()]);
```